# The plugin `libphonenumber` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding flutter

Tags: flutter

This error occurs when `flutter pub get` or `flutter run`

**

> The plugin `libphonenumber` uses a deprecated version of the Android
> embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build
> failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding.
> Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will
> remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at
> the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.**

**

Comment: I have also the same issue while using flutter flutter_qr_bar_scanner: 2.0.0.

Comment: This showed up after upgrading to flutter 2.5

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: In case you want to run your app using downgraded flutter version, you can use `flutter downgrade` command like me and it resolved my error. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is usually encountered when your project uses Flutter 2.5 and above. Literally, it means one or more packages used in your project, libphonenumber in your case, hasn't been upgraded to use Android v2 embedding. The error won't stop your code from running. If you're the package creator, you can follow this link to read more on [Flutter plugin migration](https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this package hasen't been upgraded yet. A workaround is listed on the plugins issue page:
https://github.com/natintosh/intl_phone_number_input/issues/279

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this package **intl_phone_number_input** then update to latest version. hopefully it will fix this issue.